# SearchBar / SearchDisplayController in Container overlays UITableView - iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios7, uisearchbar

this is my first question on stack overflow. I hope I will get some help :)

I'm currently updating my App to iOS 7 and I'm experiencing some problems when having a SearchDisplayController inside a ContainerView. Actually it looks like the following:

http://cl.ly/image/2Q1d0D0O1K0u

The whole content with the search bar is placed above the previous ViewController as a ChildViewController. It is it's complete own TableViewController. Now when I tap on the search bar it looks really strange with a weird animation:

http://cl.ly/image/1W2m3c1t3340

Even if I try to build this completely in storyboard (Add TableViewController, Add Container With TableViewController inside) I experience the exact same behaviour, without writing any line of code. I'm messing around with this issue for two days now and I'm not having a clue. Probably this is an iOS 7 bug? Using iOS 6 it works flawlessly.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. In my case the search bar is placed in a UITableView, right under a Segmented Control. It seems to assume the tableview is right under the navigation bar, so it animates to the wrond location when focussed and then snaps to the right location afterwards.

Comment: Thomas Moeskops look at my answer. Let me know if it helped you, too.

Comment: Have you got a project that demonstrates this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using the following code:

```c
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Odd that I read about that a ton of the time in case when the search bar overlaps the status bar. Don't know why I didn't try this earlier.

Comment: into `viewDidLoad:` of the ViewController